# IF/OR/AND statements with multiple input with multiple output calculations

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the below spreadsheet, where C8 can be one of fourteen values.

[image]

I have three different formulas that will be calculated in H8 depending on the value in C8, G8, with either D8,E8, or F8.  Where using cells D8,E8, or F8 in calculation will depend on value in C8.

I have constructed the three separate equations below which work by themselves.  I was wondering how do I string them together in one IF/OR/AND statement?

Second question how do i keep H8 to stay blank until all three cells (C8, G8, with either D8,E8, or F8) for each formula is filled out.

Equation for 0.5

```
=IF(OR(C8=0.5),(100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))),"")
```

Equation for 0.55

```
=IF(OR(C8=0.55),(100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1))),"")
```

Equation for values 0.6,0.7,0.75,1.0,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5

```
=IF(OR(C8=0.6,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5),(100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1))),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `OR`s with just a single test? Try:

```
=IF(C8=0.5,100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(C8=0.55,100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)),100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1))))
```

This tests `C8` to see if it is `0.5`, if it is, it uses the `100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))` calculation, if it isn't it test to see if it is `0.55`, if yes, it calculates `100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1))`. If not, then `C8` must be one of the other twelve values and so `100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)` is used as calculation

To keep `H8` blank until all data is entered:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTA(D8:F8)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(C8)),NOT(ISBLANK(G8))),IF(AND(C8=0.5,NOT(ISBLANK(D8))),100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(AND(C8=0.55,NOT(ISBLANK(E8))),100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(NOT(OR(C8=0.5,C8=0.55)),100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)),""))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It worked but had another question.

if C8 is any other number than those fourteen variables it still shows an answer in H8 as if it was one of those fourteen.  Also is there a way i leave H8 blank if not all conditions are filled out (C8, G8, either or D8,E8, or F8)?

Comment: Thank you so much.  that's awesome.  

one last question this there also a way to add a condition to keep H8 blank when C8 is something other than those fourteen possibilities (0.5,0.55,0.6,0.7,0.75,1.0,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5)?

Because right now if i put anyother number it still calculates as the last formula 100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)))).

Comment: You'd be better off adding [data validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29FECBCC-D1B9-42C1-9D76-EFF3CE5F7249) to `C8` (which is what I assumed you had done based on the first sentence in your question

Comment: Thank you the data validation worked.  Still one question though.
I if have 0.5 or 0.55 in the C8 cell but no value in D8 or E8 (respectively) but i do have a value in F8 (which should only be used for the 0.6-1.5 value calculation) H8 still runs a calculation.  Is there way to add a condition that if C8 shows 0.5 to only calculate if D8 & G8 is filled in and similary if C8 shows 0.55 to only calculate if E8 & G8 is filled in?  If C8 is filled but neither the D8 or E8 with G8 the resulting cell H8 will show blank?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for all the help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: If that works for you, feel free to mark the answer as correct -- we don't do this for free, you know :)

Comment: Hi, one more question.  Currently cell H8 will be blank until all cells for filled in when C8 = 0.5 or 0.55.  Can the formula be edited so that H8 will be blank if C8 equals 0.6,0.7,0.75,1.0,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375, or 1.5 until F8 & G8 are filled in?  I  tried.
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C8)),NOT(ISBLANK(G8))),IF(AND(C8=0.5,NOT(ISBLANK(D8))),100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(AND(C8=0.55,NOT(ISBLANK(E8))),100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(NOT(OR(C8=0.5,C8=0.55)),IF(AND(C8=0.6,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5,NOT(ISBLANK(F8))),(100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1))),"")))))

Comment: Adding a `COUNTA` is a simpler method: `=IF(AND(COUNTA(D8:F8)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(C8)),NOT(ISBLANK(G8))),IF(AND(C8=0.5,NOT(ISBLANK(D8))),100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(AND(C8=0.55,NOT(ISBLANK(E8))),100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(NOT(OR(C8=0.5,C8=0.55)),100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)),""))),"")`